# Cannot customize Firefox with userChrome.css

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I've tried the following actions to hide my tabs bar:

1. create folder 'chrome' in my profile directory
2. create userChrome.css in the mentioned folder
3. write the following code:
   `#TabsToolbar { visibility: collapse !important; }`

I've also changed toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets to true and browser.tabs.tabmanager.enabled to false.

Still there's no changes no matter how many times I restart the Firefox. Do you have a guess what I do wrong?

P.S.: I'm using 108.0.1 version currently

UPDATED: Nevemind. Turns out that firefox keep working when closed. I just killed the proccess and started the app again.